# Cannot inherit Shapes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance, shapes

Why I can't use a class that inherits a [`Shapes` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604615%28v=vs.90%29)?

I need to extend the `Rectangle` class with some methods, but i want to use this class in the same way I use a `Shape`, how can I do?

Comment: Careful you don't write Liskov violations... very easy to do when extending `Shape`s ... how do you want to extend `Rectangle`?

Comment: "Why I can't use a class that inherits a Shape?" - You can "I need to extend the Rectangle class with some methods, but i want to use this class in the same way I use a Shape, how can I do?" create your own class that duplicates its capability and extend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jon pointed out, Rectangle is sealed.

Depending on what you're trying to do, a couple options are:

1. You can extend Shape with your own class that contains Rectangle, and augment the functionality through composition.  These objects wouldn't be considered Rectangles from an "is" check.
2. You can write extension methods for Rectangle, and then you can use them on any Rectangle.  Then the objects would still be considered Rectangles.

e.g.

```
public static class RectangleExtensions {
    public static bool IsSquare(this Rectangle r) {
        return r.Width == r.Height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You *can* write a class which derives from `Shape`. You *can't* write a class which derives from [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx), because that's sealed.

Comment: Yes, I want to write a class which derives from Rectangle. Follow my link, i mean Shape namespace. I was not so clear.

Comment: @gliderkite: That's the `Shapes` namespace, not `Shape`. Your question is very unclear. Anyway, the answer is simply "Rectangle is sealed"...

Comment: Relevant link: [Limiting Extensibility by Sealing Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229023.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My need was similar (not methods, but properties), I needed to associate my rectangle with more properties in another class. So, my simple workaround is to utilize the DataContext property of the rectangle to store any extra information there. DataContext is an object, so it will let you add anything you desire.