# Create a class with Color, Size and Location?

Tags: c#, class, graphics, shapes

I'm creating a class that's simply a rectangle with colour.
Due to `System.Drawing.Rectangle` being a sealed type, I'm unable to do something like this:

```
class Block : Rectangle
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Block() { }
}
```

Which is basically exactly what I'd need.

---

So, is there a way to get asimilar result?
Here are few options I've thought about:

```
class Block
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Shape { get; set; }
    public Block() { }
}

class Block
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Block() { }
}
```

However, I wouldn't be able to do stuff like `Block.X` etc, and it feels stupid to "reimplement" `Rectangle`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: simple answer is that your custom type would have all the data you need to track then it would expose it to the rest of your code in neat ways

Comment: This cannot be answered - all answers will be opinion-based. There are a number of approaches that you can take but none of them is superior.

Comment: You can always encapsulate a rectangle instead of inheriting it.

Comment: You may use private fields and have properties for each of the three structures. It really depends on what kinds of use you expect..

Comment: `System.Drawing.Rectangle` isn't sealed, its a value type (struct) so it isn't inheritable (by either classes or structs). Either way you have is fine and will serve its purpose.

Comment: @RonBeyer `Error 1 'MyGame.Block': cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' F:\Skamah1\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MyGame\MyGame\Block.cs 5 11 MyGame`

Comment: @SkamahOne see the definition of it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx clearly says `public struct Rectangle`. All value types are "sealed" in that they are not inheritable, its just semantics to the compiler which is why you get that error.

Comment: @RonBeyer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142654/cannot-inherit-shapes

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that `Rectangle` is a sealed class because `Rectangle` is not a class at all. It's a struct :) . And in C# you can't inherit from the structure. That's why you will have to either reimplement it as a class or find a similar class.

Comment: I never said it's a sealed class, I said it's a **sealed type**. Here's the error I'm getting: `Error 1 'MyGame.Block': cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' F:\Skamah1\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MyGame\MyGame\Block.cs 5 11 MyGame`

Comment: @SkamahOne sorry, I've misread the question but this changes nothing. You can't ihnerit from the structure so there is no `nice` way

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a basic shape as base class. Put in what all shapes have in common in the base class:

```
public abstract class ShapeBase
{
  public Point Coordinates {get; set;}
  public Color Color {get; set;}
}
```

Then derive from that:

```
public class Rectangle : ShapeBase
{
  public int Width {get; set;}
  public int Height {get; set;}
}

public class Block : Rectangle
{
  public Size Size {get; set;}
}
```

or whatever your requirements are for the different shapes.